# How do I deploy Node.js applications as a single executable file using systemd?

Tags: javascript, node.js, containers, systemd

I want to deploy my node application as single executable file, is it possible by using systemd, containers. I dont have enough knowledge on systemd and containers. Please help me if anybody knows about it.

Comment: I think you should have a look at the `pm2` module for deployment. http://pm2.keymetrics.io/

Comment: https://blog.codeship.com/running-node-js-linux-systemd/

Comment: @NehalJWani your link does not show how to package the app into executable single file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where i work we use pm2 to run NodeJS applications.
It allows you to run multiple instances on one server, monitors them and restarts if needed (on failure or you can provide a memory limit).

If you insist going with systemd, you will have to create a unit - a file that describes the execution path of you application for systemd.

It would usually be in /usr/lib/systemd/system
You would have to create a file ending with ".service"

```
[Unit]
Description=My NodeJS App
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /path/to/my/app/index.js
```

Comment: My goal is to package the application into a 'single file' so that it can be used as an installable package.

Comment: You could pack your application into a docker image, it fits your requirement of using containers. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/

Comment: Ok. I will try.